# How can I get only href value from link

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have many links in my page.

For example `<a href="/promotions/download/schools/australia.aspx">Australia</a>`

Now I want only the href with its value i.e (href="/promotions/download/schools/australia.aspx") with vbscript regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My regex would be something like:

```
href="([^"]*)"
```

Might need escaping in your context but that (or something very much like it) should work.

Comment: don't need the brackets if he wants the href= as well. href="[^"]*"

Comment: hey guys, I have a variable "sList" which gets dyanmically filled for example <a href="/fddf/dfd/sdfd.aspx">dfd</a>. can you give write sample code from here to get complete href with values in different varaible using vbscript

Comment: Very true, but makes slicing the value out much easier (match group 0 for the whole thing, group 1 for the URI)

Comment: I could copy the code out, but you'd do better to read the whole thing: http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html

Comment: I just gave you one. Go to the link above and skip to the How to Use the VBScript RegExp Object section.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  Luckily, you should have access to the best parser available: the web browser.  Modern browsers create a [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) which is a tree structure that contains all of the information about the page.  One of the methods you can call on the DOM is links.  I don't really know vbscript, but this code looks like it should work:

```
For i = 0 To document.links.length
  document.write(document.links(i).href & "<BR>")
Next
```